# fetch particular key values from a dictionary which has values in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following dictionary, from which I want to fetch only `'tcase_name'`

```
a = {'179781': [{'exec_id': '0',
                 'exec_on_build': '',
                 'exec_on_tplan': '',
                 'exec_status': 'n',
                 'execution_duration': '',
                 'execution_order': '1',
                 'execution_type': '2',
                 'external_id': '59',
                 'feature_id': '14799',
                 'full_external_id': 'TC-59',
                 'platform_id': '0',
                 'platform_name': '',
                 'status': '1',
                 'tc_id': '179781',
                 'tcase_id': '179781',
                 'tcase_name': 'test_20experiment',  # HERE
                 'tcversion_id': '179782',
                 'tcversion_number': '',
                 'version': '1'}],
     '179821': [{'exec_id': '68588',
                 'exec_on_build': '160',
                 'exec_on_tplan': '178775',
                 'exec_status': 'b',
                 'execution_duration': '0.00',
                 'execution_order': '1',
                 'execution_type': '2',
                 'external_id': '60',
                 'feature_id': '14800',
                 'full_external_id': 'TC-60',
                 'platform_id': '0',
                 'platform_name': '',
                 'status': '1',
                 'tc_id': '179821',
                 'tcase_id': '179821',
                 'tcase_name': 'test_22experiment',  # AND HERE
                 'tcversion_id': '179822',
                 'tcversion_number': '1',
                 'version': '1'}]}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
>>> a.keys()
['179821', '179781']

>>> a.values()
[[{'tcase_id': '179821', 'status': '1', 'exec_id': '68588', 'tcversion_id': '179822', 'exec_on_tplan': '178775', 'version': '1', 'external_id': '60', 'tcversion_number': '1', 'tc_id': '179821', 'execution_type': '2', 'platform_id': '0', 'tcase_name': 'test_22experiment', 'execution_duration': '0.00', 'exec_on_build': '160', 'exec_status': 'b', 'full_external_id': 'TC-60', 'feature_id': '14800', 'execution_order': '1', 'platform_name': ''}], [{'tcase_id': '179781', 'status': '1', 'exec_id': '0', 'tcversion_id': '179782', 'exec_on_tplan': '', 'version': '1', 'external_id': '59', 'tcversion_number': '', 'tc_id': '179781', 'execution_type': '2', 'platform_id': '0', 'tcase_name': 'test_20experiment', 'execution_duration': '', 'exec_on_build': '', 'exec_status': 'n', 'full_external_id': 'TC-59', 'feature_id': '14799', 'execution_order': '1', 'platform_name': ''}]]

>>> a.values()['tcase_name']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Can someone suggest me a way to get the required field values from this dictionary?

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: Your `179781` index is referencing a list. Within that list is a dictionary. Use that knowledge to extract your required value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing the right thing. For the nested dictionary, if you can't understand it, print it out to see how it's structured.

Here is a way to get your values that you should be able to manipulate to get whatever you want.

```
for k,v in a.items():  # get the keys and values in the dict a. k, v are not special names.
    for e in v:        # now lets get all of the elements in each value, which is a list of dicts
        print(e.get('tcase_name'))  # use the dict method get to retrieve the value for a particular key of interest.
```